# Enable Places API for iOS in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

i'm trying to add `Place Autocomplete` in an iOS App but always I get this error.

`The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS.`

I'm trying to active `Places API for iOS` in Google Cloud Platform and that option does not appear in the API Library list. Someone knows why? I have seen different tutorials and posts in StackOverflow but no one explains why.

I don't know if my account needs some configuration.

Please see the attached screenshots.

Xcode error
[image]

Enable APIs and Service
[image]

API Library List
[image]

As you can see `Places API for iOS` is not in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem too but found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635966/8637144) helpful.

The problem is that the `GooglePlaces pod` is not updated. when we run `pod install` the `GooglePlaces` pod automatically sets on version `2.7.0` but the most recent is version `3.0.2`.

When trying `pod update GooglePlaces --verbose` the `pod` won't update correctly so I ended up setting the version directly on the `podfile` like this:

```
  # Pods for myProject
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.0.2'
    pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 3.0.2'
```

Then ran `pod install` again and the "api is not enabled" error was gone.

Comment: Excellent Valery this solution solved my problem, now `Place Autocomplete` it works, but I can't see `Places API for iOS` in the API List. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I believe that in the new version of the api Google might be unifying the places api so there will be no need to enable platforms individually from the api console.