# Places API not enabled for iOS even if it's already enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-places-api

I have integrated Places Autocomplete or Places API along with Maps, Google Login and Firebase RealtimeDatabase. But when I run the app, the error says:
"The operation couldn’t be completed. The Places API for iOS is not enabled. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start) for how to enable the Google Places API for iOS."

Places was working fine until:
Last week, I had to ditch my Firebase project and create a new one.
Did what was required:
-changed the GoogleServices-info.plist
-client ID
-url types

I have already enabled the Google Places API in my Google Cloud Platform, too.

And in my

```
application(didFinishLaunchingwithOptions:)
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("<key from project>")
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("<key from project>")
```

Bear in mind that Google Maps, Google Sign In and Firebase Database are all working just fine. 
The project is shared by the android version, too and the places api is working fine there. 
Can't seem to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok Asmin, so i run into the same issue this morning so i feel obligated to answer since i solved it after 5 hours! So the issue is with the pod version. GooglePlaces 2.7.0 is deprecated however when you run `pod install` 2.7.0 is what is installed not the present 3.0.2. Once i realized that, this is what i did. I opened the terminal, cd to my project folder and run `pod update`, or better yet `pod update --verbose` so i can see what's happening. Well, it worked!! The pods got updated to 3.0.2 and now everything works fine. Yaay! I love/hate programming!!

NB: anyway, if you try it and it doesn't work, then run `update repo`, and repeat `pod update`.

You have my word; it's going to work

Comment: Amazing. Thank you

Comment: Why the hell would they not warn you about this? Let alone install the correct version the first time. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I love you for this! I spend too much time dealing with this problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the correct Google account when configuring the API keys. Also make sure your key can be used for the iOS platform, double check that you enabled both `Google Maps` and `Google Places` and finally, make sure your bundle ID is allowed to use the API key.

Comment: I have already enabled both Google Maps and Google Places. I had it restricted to my bundle ID and it was still not working but I have currently not restricted the api key.
And ofcourse I am in the correct Google account.

Comment: same issue updated to 3.0.2 and check account. It says, An internal error occurred in the Places API library

Answer (score 1):

In my case nothing worked. I have updated my pod and Google Place Picker SDK version  3.0.2 .But unfortunately **Google have deprecated Google Place Picker since January 29, 2019** [Link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration#update_to_the_latest_places_client_library) .

1. I have to follow the google migration guid and Wrote my own
   controller to search for places with given string and populate those
   results in my table view [Link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration#find_autocomplete_predictions).
2. Than fetch the place detail by
       place ID [Link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration#fetch_a_place_by_id).

**Note:**  It will cost you extra API call if you want Place Detail